# Why isn't there a drop down box of editing reasons?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits

After a great learning experience over on another question where I asked about a specific editing reason on SO. It occurred to me that if you dig deep enough, there are correct reasons (that line up with the overall goal and theme of SO) and then there are reasons that run the gamut of misleading to just plain personal opinions.

That being said it seems there would be a relatively short finite list of correct reasons a post would be edited.

So couldn't there be some sort of either multi-select drop down box with only the approved editing reasons in there? That or maybe something along the line of the tag system.

I feel like it would contribute a lot, e.g.:

- Clarity for SO users when they make mistakes.
- Force editors to choose reasons that remove personal feelings and opinions.
- Reinforce the overall goal of SO (perhaps with explanation tool tips for each editing reason).
- Statistical break down – it would be great for the site over all to be able to see how many times edits were made for specific reasons, but from an individual asking questions it would be nice if after so many duplicate reasons for their questions being edited they would be presented through the messaging system with a short blurb about why that kind of editing keeps happening and direct links to Meta articles with more details.

Comment: What if I'm editing a post for multiple correct reasons? What if I'm editing a post for a correct reason that didn't make it onto the list? What if meta decides that a new reason is correct, but it takes forever to make it onto the list? No, I think this is a bad idea.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments

Comment: The same reason there isn't a drop-down box of commit reasons in your version control software—because pro-forma comments don't really do anyone any good. We want you to feel bad about leaving it blank as a motivation to fill in something unique and relevant.

Comment: Close voting culture on meta is hilarious. "Can not be reproduced"? That's a knee-slapper right there

Comment: @TinyGiant That was me in behalf of the link :)

Comment: @TinyGiant - That is why it would be a multi-select / tag system to pick multiple options and there could easily be an other option where a personal reason could be given. Those "other" option could fuel the Meta dicussions of what reasons need to be added to the list.

Comment: Sounds like an over complicated UI to me.

Comment: @TinyGiant as for the versioning it has been pointed out to me that SO is meant to be a community edited Encylopedia esque collection of facts and information. So it would not be like versioning where sometimes the reasoning is not clear cut, Can you give me some examples where an editing reason might be so far off a common list of reasons that it would warrant not trying to define a set of reasons.

Comment: @TinyGiant - Overly complicated? How? The tag system already exists so adding that logic to the current text box doesn't seem like that much of a stretch. It just seems to me that if SO has a clearly defined vision of what it should be that it wouldn't be left to wildly differing interpretations when corrections to maintain that vision are needed.

Answer (score 7):

I think that there are things that already exist that preclude the need for this feature. I'm also sure it would have plenty of negative effects.

There are a lot of times that I've left the same summary, especially when I was still suggesting edits. My browser remembered what I wrote, and offered an autocomplete drop down. This is exactly what you are describing, but without any predetermined reasons.

Besides, I suspect that the feature would be abused, much in the same way that close reasons sometimes are. I see people voting to close with reasons that just don't make sense instead of taking the time to type out a custom reason. The people who do this all have at least 3k rep.

There are just a whole lot of reasons why a post may need to be edited, but this (and the importance of clear summaries) may not become fully apparent until you get 2k rep and start working the edit queue. I certainly didn't fully appreciate it until then.

Our job as reviewers is very easy when the review summary is detailed:

*Why did they remove this tag?*
Oh, the edit summary says the tag should only be used for Java questions; this is C++.

That level of detail would vanish if we gave the option to autocomplete with "changed tags".

Comment: Lots of editors do (unfortunately) use their browser's autocomplete. I cannot tell you how many times I see suggested edits with the explanation "improved formatting", yet the edit made absolutely no change to the post's formatting.

Answer (score 0):

> and then there are reasons that run the gamut of misleading to just
>   plain personal opinions

What makes you think that there are a lot of editors giving misleading edit reasons? Misleading how?

> ...it seems there would be a relatively short finite list of correct
>   reasons a post would be edited.

That assumes that everyone interacting on a post is behaving reasonably and sometimes that isn't the case.

I'm also wondering how many options you're imagining as "relatively short" because the list I'm thinking of includes:

- Correcting grammar
- Correcting formatting
- Fixing the title to match the issue in the post
- Changed title to read like an English sentence
- Adding linked image to the post itself
- Adding linked code to the post itself
- Adding linked code mentioned in the comments* to the post itself
- Moved HTML/CSS/JavaScript into a runnable snippet
- Added placeholder images in place of broken image paths
- Adding clarification from comments
- Adding clarification OP posted as an answer instead of an edit
- Removing offensive content
- Removing off topic content
- Removing noise
- Removing extra white space
- Adding white space for readability
- Adding formatting for readability
- Adding missing tags
- Removing incorrect tags
- Removing the answer from the question
- Rolling back edit that changes the question being asked after it was answered
- Rolling back edit that defaces a post
- Added missing attribution
- Added quoted content to a link-only answer

*This would need to be a separate option because you will *not* get a post approved without explaining where the OP mentioned it; reviewers will assume you're trying to add your own code. Same with clarification (or anything you claim came from the OP).

That's just what I could think of and it's already almost the length of the page!

> Clarity for SO users when they make mistakes

Any edit summary would do that; it doesn't have to come from a drop down to be informative.

> Force editors to choose reasons that remove personal feelings and
>   opinions.

As Laurel pointed out, it'd also remove context. Also, for formatting and readability edits, you want to know why the editor thought their change was an improvement.

> Reinforce the overall goal of SO

The edit page already says what kinds of edits you should be making and why.

> it would be nice if after so many duplicate reasons for their
>   questions being edited they would be presented through the messaging
>   system with a short blurb about why that kind of editing keeps
>   happening and direct links to Meta articles with more details.

We have a large number of users who aren't native English speakers. It would be border-line hostile to have the site constantly point out that their posts have minor grammar issues. They know their English isn't perfect.

That said, a good chunk of users simply aren't going to care about this message: getting your post edited doesn't affect your reputation or, as far as I know, the question/answer ban algorithms.